# JBoss REST URL not working

Tags: java, rest, jboss

I am deploying a WAR file (vimbaserver-1.0.war) to my JBoss web server with the following web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>vimbaserver</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>vimbaserver</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.vimba.main.ServerStart</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vimbaserver</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The WAR contains two REST functions that I want to test:

```
@GET
@Path("/getWord/{word}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getWord(@PathParam("word") String word) {
    return "hello world " + " " + word;
}

@GET
@Path("/register/{userid}/{email}/{password}/{displayname}/{genderpref}/{hot}/{not}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String register(@PathParam("userid") String userid, @PathParam("email") String email, @PathParam("password") String password, @PathParam("displayname") String displayname, @PathParam("genderpref") GenderPreference gender, @PathParam("hot") int hot, @PathParam("not") int not) {
    if (userid == null || email == null || password == null
            || displayname == null || gender == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Required fields are null when registering");
    }
    try{
        RegistrationStatus status = factory.register(userid, email, password,displayname, gender.getValue(), hot, not);
        if(status == RegistrationStatus.SUCCESSFUL){
            MailSender.generateSignUpEmail(userid, email, password);
        }
        return status.getValue();
    } catch(MajorMinorException e){
        logger.error("An error occurred whilst trying to register user: ",e);
    }
    return RegistrationStatus.FAILED.getValue();
}
```

From the above, we would have expected the following REST URL to work: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/vimbaserver-1.0/functions/getWord/test. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

What is strange is that we have another application deployed to our server that exposes a number of REST functions that appear to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in `web.xml` your `URL` pattern is  `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` so `URL` should be,

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/vimbaserver-1.0/rest/functions/getWord/test
                                       ^^^^^^^Add rest in your url
```

Make sure your service class contains `@Path("/functions")` at start and annotated properly.It sounds like you missed some annotation(s). For example `@Service` or `@Component` please check.

Comment: Just gave this a try and JBoss returned a "Could not find resource for relative : /rest/functions/getWord/test of full path: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/vimbaserver-1.0/rest/functions/getWord/test" error.

Comment: Thought about what you said regarding the URL pattern, changed ours to /* to include all of our resources. This seems to have done the trick. Thank you.